# performing actions based on UIsegmented control name

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to perform various actions based on UIsegmented control name.

Here is my code :

```
- (UIView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [cell.mySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

UIsegemented control have two index name as accept and reject.

```
- (void) segmentValueChanged: (UISegmentedControl *) sender {

    if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        // I am changing the UISegmented control index name
        [sender setTitle:@"SEND TO ADMIN" forSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];
        [sender setTitle:@"EVALUATE" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    }
    else
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

Again, I need to trigger functions when I tap SEND TO ADMIN and same for EVALUATE.

How to write conditions based on UISegmented control name.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: alerasy you have the answer then why you posted the question , for SEND TO ADMIN == 0 do your action

Comment: No i tried it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the title of the selected segment using the following code:

```
  NSInteger selectedIndex = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];
  NSString *selectedTitle = [sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:selectedIndex];

    if ([selectedTitle isEqual:@"SEND TO ADMIN"] || [selectedTitle isEqual:@"EVALUATE"]) {
        // Call your function here
    }
```

Add it in your `- (void) segmentValueChanged: (UISegmentedControl *) sender` function.